# Public Members vs Constructor of a Class in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, class, constructor

I have a doubt.

```
1. namespace JIMS.ViewModel.Stock
2. {
3.     internal class StockGroupViewModel : JIMS.ViewModel.BaseViewModel
4.     {
5.         JIMSEntities dbContext = new JIMSEntities();
6. 
7.         public StockGroupViewModel()
8.         {                     
9.          dbContext = new JIMSEntities();
10.        }
11.    }
12. }
```

I have this class. And i want to know which is called first.
when i create an instance of this class

```
StockGroupViewModel s = new StockGroupViewModel();
```

`Line 5 or Line 9.`

Comment: In this case, I'm not sure it matters, but I'd go with 5. You should delete the constructor here.

Comment: You could have set a breakpoint. BrokenGlass is correct

Comment: Ok, thats why i was getting this error 'Cannot create instance of StockGroupViewModel' in the View

Comment: Very detailed explanation of initialization order here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920615/field-initialization

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Line 5 - it's a field initializer which is executed before any code within the constructor.

From the spec:

> 10.5.5.2 Instance field initialization
>
> The instance field variable initializers of a class correspond to a sequence of assignments that
> **are executed immediately upon entry to any one of the instance
> constructors (§10.11.1) of that class**. The variable initializers are
> executed in the textual order in which they appear in the class
> declaration. The class instance creation and initialization process is
> described further in §10.11.

Answer (score 2):

Field initializers called prior to body of constructor. So, line 5 called before line 9.

Answer (score 1):

Line 5, fields are initialized before constructor is called.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will embed the field initializer in the code for the constructor, so that is called first and *then* the field is initialized again by the call in the constructor. Looking at the IL for the code makes this very obvious.

E.g. code like this

```
class Foo
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1);

    public Foo()
    {
        sb = new StringBuilder(2);
    }
}
```

looks like this at the IL level

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: ldc.i4.1  <-- ARGUMENT = 1
    L_0002: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder::.ctor(int32)
    L_0007: stfld class [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder playground.Foo::o
    L_000c: ldarg.0 
    L_000d: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    L_0012: nop 
    L_0013: nop 
    L_0014: ldarg.0 
    L_0015: ldc.i4.2  <-- ARGUMENT = 2
    L_0016: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder::.ctor(int32)
    L_001b: stfld class [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder playground.Foo::o
    L_0020: nop 
    L_0021: ret 
}
```