# Static constructor not called before static fields

Tags: c#, .net, static, clr

I have a class as follows :

```
static class Configuration
    {
        private static AppSettingsSection _appSettingsLogsSection;
        static Configuration()
        {
            var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            _appSettingsLogsSection = config.GetSectionGroup("Logs").Sections["appSettings"] as AppSettingsSection;
        }

        public static int LogSendIntervalMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(_appSettingsLogsSection.Settings["LogSendIntervalMinutes"]);

    }
```

Now, as per my understanding, the static constructor should be called before the first reference to any static member is made. But surprisingly, it is not behaving like that. When I reference **LogSendIntervalMinutes** from Main class, instead of triggering the static constructor, call goes straight to the static field resulting in a NullReferenceException. 


Am I doing something wrong here and is my understanding correct?

Comment: Look at the compile code using `ILSpy` or `Reflector` you will find your answer. Actually field initializers are automatically moved inside constructor before your actual code of constructor. (static moves to static one and instance to instance contructor).

Comment: I have added a snapshot in answer for your class using reflector for your reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> The static field variable initializers of a class correspond to a
>   sequence of assignments that are executed in the textual order in
>   which they appear in the class declaration.

So try to move the initialization to before the `static` constructor, or include the association in the `static` constructor itself.

And even though, you are trying something impossible, since the static field uses a variable declared inside the static constructor.

Try this:

```
private static AppSettingsSection _appSettingsLogsSection;
public static int LogSendIntervalMinutes;

static Configuration()
{
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    _appSettingsLogsSection = config.GetSectionGroup("Logs").Sections["appSettings"] as AppSettingsSection;

    LogSendIntervalMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(_appSettingsLogsSection.Settings["LogSendIntervalMinutes"]);        }
}
```

Comment: Now I got it, thanks.
Although all answers explained more or less the same thing, I am marking this as answer as it was the first one :)

Answer (score 5):

Static fields are always initialized before static constructor is called. You should initialize `LogSendIntervalMinutes` in static constructor as well. I'd suggest you even make it a property:

```
static class Configuration
{
    private static AppSettingsSection _appSettingsLogsSection;
    public static int LogSendIntervalMinutes { get; private set; }
    static Configuration()
    {
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        _appSettingsLogsSection = config.GetSectionGroup("Logs").Sections["appSettings"] as AppSettingsSection;
        LogSendIntervalMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(_appSettingsLogsSection.Settings["LogSendIntervalMinutes"]);
    }
}
```

Quote from [C# language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) (I added the emphasis):

> 10.4.5.1 Static field initialization
>
> The static field variable initializers of a class correspond to a
>   sequence of assignments that are executed in the textual order in
>   which they appear in the class declaration. **If a static constructor
>   (Section 10.11) exists in the class, execution of the static field
>   initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that static
>   constructor.** Otherwise, the static field initializers are executed
>   at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of a static
>   field of that class.

Comment: I can't find a solid resource for the object initialization order, but [both](http://www.csharp411.com/c-object-initialization/) [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920615/field-initialization) posts refer to the same sequence that reinforces this.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the compile code using `ILSpy` or `Reflector` you will find your answer.

Actually ***field initializers are automatically moved inside constructor before your actual code of constructor***. (*static moves to static one and instance to instance contructor*).

Decompile code of your class using reflector:

[image]

and actual class structure look like this:

[image]

Also you can see the optimization done by compiler to integrate two separate lines in constructor to single line to initialize _appSettingsLogsSection.

Answer (score 1):

Initializations of static fields are actually part of the type constructor and are executed before the custom type constructor is called. Thus, if `LogSendIntervalMinutes` was an instance field, there would be no problem, but as it is static, its initialization is executed before your static constructor. You just need to put the initialization of `LogSendIntervalMinutes` inside the your type constructor.