# CanExecute in DelegateCommand and expression declaration doesn't work

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

My question is straightforward.
Why this works:

```
public DelegateCommand LogInCommand { get; }

Func<bool> canExecuteLogIn = () => !StringService.IsNullOrEmpty(_entries.LoginText, _entries.PasswordText);
LogInCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnLogInTapped, canExecuteLogIn);
```

But this doesn't:

```
public DelegateCommand LogInCommand => new DelegateCommand(OnLogInTapped,
            () => !StringService.IsNullOrEmpty(_entries.LoginText, _entries.PasswordText));
```

I check like so:

```
 public string LoginEntryText
        {
            get { return _entries.LoginText; }
            set
            {
                _entries.LoginText = value;
                LogInCommand?.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
```

Doesn't work, I mean that Func never executes after initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is not entirely clear for me, but I suspect the reason is as follows.

This

```
public DelegateCommand LogInCommand => new DelegateCommand(...)
```

Is equivalent to this

```
public DelegateCommand LogInCommand { get {return new DelegateCommand(...)}}
```

So every time you access `LogInCommand` property - it returns new `DelegateCommand` instance. That means you do `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` on fresh instance of a command, and all code that called this property before and which can react to this change use their own instances.

That's unlike first scenario where there is just one instance of `DelegateCommand` used by everyone.

Comment: I thought that expression declaration checks, if an instance was created, internally. 
But why if I do initialization like you suggested, I have to have fields, that are in use to be static? It means that `=>` and `=` has different initialization mechanism?

Comment: Sure `=>` and `=` are different. I've shown in answer what is equivalent of `=>` initialization (for properties, not in general). I didn't understand your first sentence "I have to have fields, that are in use to be static" though.

Comment: It says me "Cannot access non-static field "_entries"  in static context". It also relates to OnLogInTapped.

Comment: Ah I missed you access fields in your delegate. Yes then you cannot use that syntax, because it's analog to declaring `readonly` field as a backing field for your property, and you cannot do that in field initializer (see here a little explanation - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7400757/5311735) . So your best bet would be to just use first syntax.

Comment: It's weird and not clear why `=>` allow to use this fields, and `=` don't. I would like to get a better understanding. But to do it in a constructor is just ok. 
Thank you for your afforts.

Comment: I'll try to explain. As I described, `=>` is complete analog of `{get{return new ...}}`. When getter is executed in this case - instance is already constructed and all fields (such as `_entities`) are initialized. So, constructor has been already run. When you do `{get;} = new ...`, it's analog of declaring a field like this: `_logInCommand = new ...`. When this field initializer is being run - constructor has not been run yet. Your `_entities` field is not initialized yet and so cannot be used (even though you are using it not directly but in delegate).

Comment: Does properties initialization go after constructor?
What I knew, that when I write `{get;} = new`, it executes in constructor anyway. It is just a way of declaring.
Does `{get;}=new` is different from just `Property = new Property();` ? (I mean in initialization)

Comment: `Property = new Property()` is not a property - it's a field. `Property {get;} = new ..` is a property backed by readonly field (so: `Property {get {return _property;}} _property = new ...`. Field initializers run _before_ constructor, and so you cannot reference instance members there. I suggest you to read this answer for more clarity: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1920814/5311735.

Comment: Now I understand. You got my personal respect for your intention to help.